# Как получить значения скрытого поля html с помощью JS?

Tags: php, javascript

Здравствуйте, подскажите пожалуйста как получить значение из скрытого поля html

```
<input type = 'hidden' name = 'id'>
```

Вот допустим у меня в БД есть 10 записей и с каждой записи есть ID и когда я вывожу я добавляю кнопку к выводимой информации:

```
<form action = "" method = "post" name = "delete">
<input type = "hidden" name = "id" value = "<?=$id?>">
Логин пользователя: <input type = "text" name = "username" value = "<?=$username?>">
<input type = "submit" value = "Удалить пользователя">
</form>
```

Так вот из этого списка когда я нажимал на кнопку Удалить пользователя я бы удалил именно того напротив которого была эта кнопка, я пытался сделать так:

```
$("form[name='delete']").submit(function(){
    var id = $("input[name = 'id']").val();
    $.post("ajax.php" ,{id:id, action:"delete"}, function(){
      alert("Пользователь удалён");
    });
    return false;
});
```

Но проблема заключается в том, что ID который я беру из скрытого поля всегда один и тот-же, выводится нормально:

1. admin
2. user
3. banned
4. moder

И у всех свой ID, но когда я нажимаю на кнопку, берётся только ID самого первого в списке пользователя.

```
<?php
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tb_company WHERE active = '1'");
if(mysql_num_rows($sql) > 0){
while($res = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)){
    $id = $res["id"];
    $allBuy = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tb_user_stock WHERE id_company = '$id'");
    $allBuy = mysql_num_rows($allBuy);

    echo "
    <tr style = 'text-align: center; border-bottom: 2px solid black;' class = 'td_link'>
        <form action = '' method = 'post' name = 'buy_form'>
            <input type = \"hidden\" name = \"id\" value = \"$id\">
            <td>" .$res["name"] ."</td>
            <td>" .$res["price"] ."</td>
            <td>" .$res["percent"] ."</td>
            <td>" .$res["summ"] ."</td>
            <td>$allBuy</td>
            <td><input type = 'text' name = 'count' size = '4' value = '1'></td>
            <td><input type = 'submit' name = 'buy' value = 'Купить'></td>
        </form>
    </tr>
    ";
}
```

}
?>

Answer (score 2):

Присвойте уникальный атрибут id каждому полю hidden. А вообще-то делается это как-то так:

```
<label>
    <input type="radio" name="deleteUser" value="<?=$id?>" />
    Удалить Васю
</label>
```

Answer (score 2):

Ну потому что этот код

```
$("input name = [name = 'id']").val()
```

вообще непонятно что выбирает из вашего HTML, скорее всего результатом является `null` и PHP удаляет запись с `id = 0`. Я в этом не уверен, но скорее всего так оно и есть.

id необходимо искать в контексте отправленной формы (изменилась только вторая строка):

```
$("form[name='delete']").submit(function(){
    var id = $(this).find("input[name='id']").val();
    $.post("ajax.php" ,{id:id, action:"delete"}, function(){
      alert("Пользователь удалён");
    });
    return false;
});
```

Comment: $("input name = [name = 'id']").val();

Ой извиняюсь, вот такой

    $("input [name = 'id']").val();

Answer (score 2):

Все правильно у вас берется, т.к. `form[name='delete']` у вас именно столько сколько и пользователей. Решение может быть следующее

```
$("form[name='delete']").submit(function(){
        var id = $(this).find("input[name = 'id']").val();
        $.post("ajax.php" ,{id:id, action:"delete"}, function(){
        alert("Пользователь удалён");
    });
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Ну тогда выводит: undefined

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/JsSYf/3/

Comment: А если у меня много форм и они выводятся в цикле? Т.е примерно так(посмотрите самый первый пост)

Comment: так там где работают 2 работает и 100, я же вам пример в jsfiddle вывел посмотрите там все хорошо а потом комментируйте что вы там в цикле выводите. Вам 2 человеко в одно и то же время один и тот же ответ дали.

Comment: Я посмотрел и проверил на html страничке все работает как часы, а на php ничего не работает постоянно выводит: undefined, я уже этот Js скрипт куда только не пихал чтобы заработал... Да и ещё если ПОСЛЕ php скрипта сделать отдельно форму(без цикла и т.д, как у вас в примере), то код работает...

Comment: Следсвенно у вас PHP не правильно выводит <input type ="hidden" name="id" value="<?=$id?>"> и проблема скорее всего именно в <?=$id?>

Comment: А также может быть проблема в самом PHP коде, который удаляет пользователя.

Comment: вообще так для вашего решения не совсем нужна форма, но если уж выводится то попробуйте по другому:
для начала оберните все в:
$(document).ready(function(){
//Здес тот код что был выше
});
Может инициализация скрипта происходит раньше чем загрузился весь DOM Document

Comment: http://phpfiddle.org/lite/code/4cu-tkb прокомментируйте там есть кнопка run просто реально понять не могу, что же вы там пишите что у вас не получается.

Comment: Скажите можно я вам файл с этим кодом пришлю, чтобы вы увидели о чём я?